# Browser closes after completing the first scenario in Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

In my Specflow project, I have defined two scenarios in my feature file. But When I execute my program, browser closes after the first scenario. Then It fails the test, since there is no connection with the remote server.

How Can I solve this?

```
Feature: Check functionality of dashboard

@SmokeTest
@Browser:Chrome
Scenario: Check dashboard page is loaded
    Given I have navigated to application
    And I typed emailid and password
    | Email           | Password |
    | qa02@example.com | test1234 |
    When I clicked login button
    Then I should see dashboard

Scenario: Check trading partners page is loaded
    Given I am on Trading Partner page
    When I click on trading partners link
    Then I should see trading partners page
```

Following is my Package.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Autofac.Configuration" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="ExcelDataReader" version="2.1.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="ImpromptuInterface" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.18" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.1.18" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.0.12054" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" version="2.30" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Please see the related step file.

```
namespace DX2Functional.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    class DashboardSteps
    {


        [Given(@"I have navigated to application")]
        public void GivenIHaveNavigatedToLoginUrl()
        {
            Browser.Current.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seleniumBaseUrl"]);
            CommonMethods.driver = Browser.Current;
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage = new Login();
        }

        [Given(@"I typed emailid and password")]
        public void GivenITypedEmailidAndPassword(Table table)
        {
            dynamic tableDetails = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
            string email = tableDetails.Email;
            Console.Write("Email is " + email);
            string passowrd = tableDetails.Password;
            Console.Write("password is " + passowrd);

            PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<Login>().enterUerEmailAndPassword(email, passowrd);
        }

        [When(@"I clicked login button")]
        public void WhenIClickedLoginButton()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage = PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<Login>().clickLoginButton();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see dashboard")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeDashboard()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<Dashboard>().IsloadedIn();
        }


        [Given(@"I am on Trading Partner page")]
        public void GivenIamOnTradingPartnerPage()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<Dashboard>().IsloadedIn();
        }

        [When(@"I click on trading partners link")]
        public void WhenIClickOnTradingPartnersLink()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<Dashboard>().clickTradingPrtnersLink();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see trading partners page")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeTradingPartnersPage()
        {
            PropertiesCollection.currentPage.As<TradingPartners>().IsTPListLoaded();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a hooks file with an AfterScenario method? Or can you share the code where you are quiting or closing the webdriver?

Comment: I don't have any hooks file. And also I don't explicitly close the browser

Comment: Which library are you using for automating the browser? Could you post your package.config? And could you share the binding code of the steps you have in these scenarios?

Comment: I have attached my package.config and steps file here.

Comment: Can someone please help me? Here I have added my feature file and steps definitions file as well

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this issue is to use a `Background` instead of a `Scenario` for the first part of your feature file which logs in the user.

For example:

```
Feature: Check functionality of dashboard

@SmokeTest
@Browser:Chrome
Background: 
    Given I have navigated to application
    And I typed emailid and password
    | Email           | Password |
    | qa02@example.com | test1234 |
    When I clicked login button

Scenario: Check dashboard page is loaded    
    Then I should see dashboard

Scenario: Check trading partners page is loaded
    Given I am on Trading Partner page
    When I click on trading partners link
    Then I should see trading partners page
```